# Fixed position won't let me scroll and relative position won't stretch the div

Tags: html, css

thanks for helping out. I have a site with a container div that I'd like to stretch to the bottom of the page. Using `position: fixed` I'm able to achieve this, but the footer text on the bottom is cutoff and you are unable to scroll down.

Using `position: relative` I'm able to scroll, but the container div does not stretch to the bottom of the page.

My code is as follows:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -480px;
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #1b1a1a;
}

.body {
  width: 703px;
  min-height: 340px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="body">
    content content content
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you just want it to stretch to the bottom of the page, why don't you use an absolute position? (for example: http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/jrsxN/2/) Can you please make your issue more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/jrsxN/7/

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1b1a1a;
}
.body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px 20px 120px;
}
.footer {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    background:#f00;
}
```